# it is possible to export an a-frame project to a 360 ° image

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

I wanted to know if it is possible to export a project made in a-frame to a jpg / png image with the correct metadata to show them in flicker or facebook.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a 360° (equirectangular) screenshot by simply pressing:

`<ctrl> + <alt> + <shift> + s`

A-frame's simple scene:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use three.js api for that - create a cubemap camera, capture a frame from it and then you can convert a cubemap to equirectangular. One of projects that does just this is https://github.com/imgntn/j360